# Fabric, Crashylitics stacktraces not deobfuscated. Android

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

So Fabric is not deobfuscating any of the stacktraces completely...
It does do so partially, and i notice it attaches some random unknown methods to the stack traces which are nowhere associated to the code in context.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.content.Context in.ulink.agrostar.agroex.b.a.j.e()' on a null object reference
   at in.ulink.agrostar.agroex.presenter.HomePresenter.fetchLeadsFromApi(method 'onItemClicked':344)
   at in.ulink.agrostar.agroex.presenter.HomePresenter.syncOfflineLeadsAdded(method 'onItemClicked')
   at in.ulink.agrostar.agroex.presenter.HomePresenter$3.onPostExecute(method 'onItemClicked':554)
   at in.ulink.agrostar.agroex.presenter.HomePresenter$3.onPostExecute(method 'onItemClicked':540)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This is what is there in my ProGuard mapping file

```
#FOR CRASHLYTICS 
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

Could someone share what they have done so that Crashlytics (Fabric) gives exact stacktrace when I run on debug mode without ProGuard.

Answer (score 3):

Mike from Fabric here.

Currently, we're unable to de-obfuscate the message part of the error, but your Proguard config needs a couple of changes. I'd add:

```
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
```

also, remove this if present:

```
-printmapping mapping.txt
```

We won't add anything to the stack trace that is not present or found when using a mapping file.

Comment: ya the docs said about -printmapping thats already there..ill add the Exception thing and check. Thank you very much

Comment: Hey @Mike it doesnt work sometimes, any idea why the crash traces are not deobfuscated partially and it comes as a different crash replort sometimes for some users instead of being appended to the same. Any thoughts?

Comment: There are a number of reasons why this could be happening, I'd recommend sending links of the issues where you see this happening to support(at)fabric(dot)io

Comment: Thank you. I have unmarked it for now, will come back and give update so as to not mislead other users. Hope thats okay.

Comment: @MikeBonnell is there still issue with message part of stacktrace?

Comment: Since the message is a string, we don't try to de-obfuscate as there is no guarantee that code will be present.